# UML Statecharts or state machine in parallel region

Tags: concurrency, parallel-processing, uml, statechart

I'm now looking for a book mainly focusing on UML statecharts in parallel region. It's pretty hard to find one. Most of the book only contain so little information and I wonder whether there is a book concentrating on this topic. If there is, I really appreciate that you guys could tell me about it! UML statecharts in parallel region or concurrent statecharts will be fine!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that the state machine diagram is not for multitasking planning. The *time diagram* is for it. Of course, you can combine these two, but it is not a standard solution.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel regions in state machine or in composite state are common. If used, modeler define, that system which behavior is described this way is in two or more states at the same time.
For example, if you define state as executional, it means that system executes some behavior during state is active, you can simply define concurrent execution of different behaviors. All active states must reside in different regions !
The best information resource is UML Specification from OMG